# How to raise an event in Angular 1.5 Component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using Angular 1.5 Component in my application. I have a root component for configuration my routes:

```
module.component("myApp", {
    templateUrl: "/app/components/my-app.component.html",
    $routeConfig: [
        { path: "/list", component: "myList", name: "List" },
        { path: "/login", component: "login", name: "Login" },
        { path: "/**", redirectTo: [ "List" ] }
    ]
});
```

I also have a component called `login-partial` inside `my-App` component for showing login for logout menu:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="#/login">Login</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Now, inside my `login-conponent`'s controller I want to change `login-partial` template (changing the `login` item to `logout`):

```
function loginController(account, $location) {
    var model = this;
    var onComplete = function (data) {
        if (data === "ok") {
            $location.url('/list');
        }
    };
    model.login = function (userName, password) {
        account.login(userName, password)
            .then(onComplete, onError);
    };
};
module.component("login", {
    templateUrl: "/app/components/login.component.html",
    controllerAs: "model",
    controller: ["account", "toaster", "$location", loginController]
});
```

With directives we could raise an event using `$scope.$emit() and $scope.$on()`. But as far as I know the new component introduced in Angular 1.5 doesn't support events.

Is it possible with components? Any suggestion as to how one would achieve doing this?

Comment: Component is [a thin sugar coating](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.5.5/src/ng/compile.js#L1111) around directive. It can do the same things as directive and doesn't prevent using `$scope` in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using `$rootScope` and dispatch an event from `loginController`:

```
function loginController(account, toaster, $location, $rootScope) {
    var model = this;

    var onComplete = function (data) {
        if (data === "ok") {
            $rootScope.$emit('success', { data: true });
            $location.url('/list');
        }
        // other code
    };
    var onError = function (reason) {
        // other code
    };

    model.login = function (userName, password) {
        account.login(userName, password)
            .then(onComplete, onError);
    };

};
```

Then inside `partialLoginController` I listen to that event:

```
function partialLoginController($rootScope) {
    var model = this;
    model.isLoggedIn = false;

    $rootScope.$on('success', function (event, args) {
        model.isLoggedIn = args.data;
        console.log(args.data);
    }); 
};
```